# How to summarise Data Using Python 3.7?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have CSV file that I convert into a dictionary. A row in the dictionary looks like this:-

```
OrderedDict([('MVA', '10072672'), ('Code', 'F5'), ('Tbk Mnth', '01-Dec-16'), ('Branch', 'W0S'), ('Make', 'VOLKSWAGENRSA'), ('Status', 'RISK'), ('Price', '111200.27')])
```

I am trying to sum the value in column 'Price' but n = 0. What am I doing wrong? Also what is the most efficient way to sum the different codes?

```
import csv
linecount = 0
with open(r'C:\Users\anthony\Documents\Test\Data.csv') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
        code = (row["Code"])
        if code == 'F5':
            linecount += 1

    print(linecount)



    n = sum([item['Price'] for item in reader])
    print(n)
```

Comment: You already reached the end of the reader using the loop:
`for row in reader`
That is why there are no data left

Comment: What error do you get? Does the program crash or does it give wrong output? If it's the latter case, what do you want to achieve and what you actually get? I think that you placed `sum` in the wrong place since it does not have access to `reader` data, but please confirm this.

Comment: @gonczor OP mentions the problem; they get n = 0, so it's the wrong output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is you can't iterate the reader twice.

The `defaultdict` class in the `collections` module is handy for grouping items.
Here, we're gathering the `Price`s (cast into `Decimal`s for precision) into a dict of lists, then summing them afterwards.

```py
import csv
import decimal
import collections

# Defaultdicts are handy in that they never have nonexistent keys;
# if you access an nonexistent key, the constructor (`list` here)
# is invoked.

prices_by_code = collections.defaultdict(list)

with open(r'Data.csv') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    for row in reader:
        price = row.get('Price')
        code = row.get('Code')
        if code and price:
            prices_by_code[code].append(decimal.Decimal(price))

# By this time,  `prices_by_code` looks approximately like
# {"5": [1, 2, 3], "8": [4, 5, 6]}

for code, prices in sorted(prices_by_code.items()):
    print(code, sum(prices))
```

Comment: When I run your code I receive the following error:- prices_by_code[row["Code"]].append(decimal.Decimal(item["Price"]))
NameError: name 'item' is not defined

Comment: Oops, I meant `row["Price"]`.

Comment: Tried that! Now I receive the following error:    prices_by_code[row["Code"]].append(decimal.Decimal(row["Price"]))
KeyError: 'Price'

Comment: Does every row actually have a `Price` column?

Comment: (Modified the code to add a guard against that case.)

Comment: Yip Column header is Price

Answer (score 0):

`reader` is an iterator. By iteratorating over it you consume its values. If you need to keep these values then you must store somewhere else. The easiest way to do this is to create a list from the iterator and then iterate over the list instead.

Eg.

```
rows = list(reader)

for row in rows:
   ...

n = sum([item['Price'] for item in rows])
```

However, the price will be a string and not a float. So you will your list comprehension to convert them to a float. Eg. `float(item['Price'])`